# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1

Tags: java, maven, android-studio, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm totally new to android studio and came up to this error that says it can not download `gradle-3.5.1.pom` and `gradle-3.5.1.jar` from **google** or **jcenter** repositories. But when I tried downloading them manually it was easy and straight forward though.

Here is the error text :

```
ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.1/gradle-3.5.1.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.1/gradle-3.5.1.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.1/gradle-3.5.1.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.1/gradle-3.5.1.jar
Required by:
    project :
Open File
```

I know that this is going to make me crazy because these gradle stuff always been a problem to all.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have `google()` repo in your project's level build.gradle file.
Here's an example:

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // check if you have this
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // and this
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I have it in build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Disable Offline Work in Android studio if you have enabled the checkbox and sync project. 
Once the project is synced, you can enable the checkbox and run the app as long as you do not add another dependency manually.
It will automatically download the required dependencies. 
File>Settings>Build>Gradle